# FromBtcAsync Error

Tags: c#, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

I'm new in BlockChain and I'm using https://blockchain.info/api c# for the project.

I getting this error `One or more errors occurred. (Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 1.)`. When param `btc` is `0.1` and lower it success.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConvertBTCToCurrency(decimal btc, string currency)
{
    var error = "";
    try
    {
        var btcVal = new BitcoinValue(btc);
        explorer = new ExchangeRateExplorer();
        var btcAmountResult = explorer.FromBtcAsync(btcVal, currency).Result;
        return Json(new { statusCode = 200, worthCurrency = btcAmountResult });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        error = e.Message;
    }
    return Json(new { statusCode = 201, worthCurrency = error });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `async/await` pattern for FromBtcAsync method?

Comment: @Eugene any example to show me ?

Comment: `var btcAmountResult = await explorer.FromBtcAsync(btcVal, currency)`